# CryptGenRandom output not getting same as rand() call

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, visual-c++

I tried to create random number using CryptGenRandom() call for avoiding cryptographic attack.
I tried to run follwing code which prints both rand call and CryptGenRandom() call.

```
    HCRYPTPROV hProvider = 0;

    const DWORD dwLength = 5;

    BYTE pbBuffer[dwLength] = {};

    if (!::CryptAcquireContext(&hProvider, 0, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL,  CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT|CRYPT_SILENT))

    return 1;

    srand((unsigned)time (0));
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        cout<<"rand()::"<<i<<":"<<rand()<<endl;

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwLength; ++i)
    {
        if (!::CryptGenRandom(hProvider, dwLength, pbBuffer))
        {
            ::CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0);
            return 1;
        }
     std::cout << "windows::"<<i<<"::"<<static_cast<unsigned int>(pbBuffer[0])<< std::endl;
    }

    if (!::CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0))
    return 1;
```

but output of this getting for `rand()` call is

```
rand()::0:9754
rand()::1:526
rand()::2:29162
rand()::3:10461
rand()::4:31585
rand()::5:15594
rand()::6:12157
rand()::7:19178
rand()::8:5413
rand()::9:16157
```

and `CryptGenRandom()` call is giving

```
windows::0::167
windows::1::138
windows::2::197
windows::3::101
windows::4::44
```

Can anyone help me to get same output which is giving rand() call using CryptGenRandom?
CryptGenRandom() is giving only 3 digit random numbers which not sufficient for setting values for sleep calls which I am using in my code.

Comment: Uhm... **no**. `CryptGenRandom` is a cryptographically secure PRNG. If you could have it produce a specific sequence on demand that would be a **huge** problem. What's the problem you think you have with the output from `CryptGenRandom`?

Comment: It's only giving 3-digit integer outputs _because you're only using the first BYTE_. Try `*static_cast<unsigned *>(pbBuffer)` and compare ...

Comment: I tried to change BYTE but it is not working. Can you please help me for using that.

Comment: Yes. Use `CryptGenRandom` properly.

Comment: @Useless: That cast isn't safe due to alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of `pBuffer[0]` here.

```
 static_cast<unsigned int>(pbBuffer[0])
```

As your code shows, `pBuffer[0]` is a single `BYTE`.  That's why you're not getting values greater than 255.

If you want any representable `unsigned int`, you'll want this.

```
const DWORD dwLength = sizeof(unsigned int);
```

And this, to use all the bytes in `pBuffer`.

```
 *static_cast<unsigned int*>(pbBuffer)
```

Comment: If I tring to do that it is showing following error:           error C2664: 'CryptGenRandom' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'unsigned
 int [4]' to 'BYTE *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast
 or function-style cast

Comment: @DrewDorman: That pointer cast is unsafe, the buffer may not be properly aligned for `unsigned int`.

Comment: @MooingDuck In addition, this won't fix another (small) issue with the original code: calling `CryptGenRandom` 5 times (to generate 4 bytes) when one will do.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, it's only giving 3 digit numbers because you are taking only one byte and converting it to an `unsigned int` when you do this: `static_cast<unsigned int>(pbBuffer[0])` and a `BYTE` (i.e. an `unsigned char`) can only fit values between 0 and 255.

You can change your approach slightly:

```
unsigned int MyGoodRand()
{
    // We make this a static so we don't have
    // to initialize it all the time because
    // that is expensive.
    static HCRYPTPROV hProvider = 0;

    if(hProvider == NULL) 
    {
        if(!::CryptAcquireContext(&hProvider, 0, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL, 
                                  CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT|CRYPT_SILENT))
            return 0;
    }

    unsigned int randval = 0;

    if (!::CryptGenRandom(hProvider, sizeof(unsigned int), static_cast<PBYTE>(&randval)))
        randval = 0; // Failure!

    return randval;
}
```

This function will return `0` on failure which is a problem, because 0 is also a possible result from `CryptGenRandom` and additionally will leak the `HCRYPTPROV` because it's only available inside the function and once allocated there's no way to release it.

We could augmented it to return `true` or `false` accordingly and accept `randval` by reference from its caller, but that wouldn't solve the `HCRYPTPROV` leak. Let's instead make a `class` which has the `HCRYPTPROV` as a member along with an `operator()` which will be used to generate new numbers.

Something like this:

```
class MYPRNG
{
private:
    HCRYPTPROV hProvider;

    // declare but not define a private copy constructor to
    // prevent copy-construction of this object. If you're
    // using C++11 you can use the =delete syntax instead.
    MYPRNG(const MYPRNG &o) = delete; 

    // Same with the default assignment operator.
    MYPRNG& operator=(const MYPRNG& o)

public:
    MYPRNG()
        : hProvider(NULL)
    {
        if(!::CryptAcquireContext(&hProvider, 0, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL, 
                                  CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT|CRYPT_SILENT))
            hProvider = NULL; // ensure that it's NULL
    }

    ~MYPRNG()
    {
        if(hProvider)
            CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0);
    }

    bool operator()(unsigned int &randval)
    { 
        if(hProvider == NULL)
            return false;

        if (!::CryptGenRandom(hProvider, 
                              sizeof(unsigned int), 
                              static_cast<PBYTE>(&randval)))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
};
```

Now we have no leaks and we can easily generate random numbers and determine if the operation succeeded or failed reliably. We can use it like this:

```
MYPRNG prng;
unsigned int rval;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ // try to get 10 random numbers!
    if(!prng(rval))
    {
        // FAILED TO GENERATE A NEW RANDOM NUMBER!
    }
    else
    {
        // A new random number is now in rval. Use it
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone can help me to get full number instead of one byte.If I try to print like that it is giving error which I posted above.

Comment: I tried to build following code and getting same output when calling from out side in loop.

Comment: @user1488334: which code? Can you show us *exactly* what you called and how?